# How to extend a class in dart using the same class name

Tags: inheritance, dart, extend

Is there a way to extend a class in dart using the same name as its parent, like java does?
Something like this...:

```
class Connection extends com.mypackage.Connection{
    ...
}
```

By defining the parent class with the package name I'm able to extend the class with the same name, but is this possible in dart???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart you can import another library with a prefix. This allows you to qualify the reference to the name, so it doesn't conflict with the same name in the current library:

```dart
import "other_connection.dart" as other;
class Connection extends other.Connection { 
  ...
}
```

This can also be used to qualify conflicting names from two different imports.

(A Dart library has a default import scope where imported names are added, and which can be referenced directly. The `as prefix` qualifyer on an import means that that import is put into a different import scope, which you can reference by `prefix`. More than one library can be imported into the same prefixed import scope.)

If you are using more names from the same import, and only one of them is conflicting, you can import the same library both with and without a prefix.
Say, `other_connection.dart` declares both `Connection` and `Disconnection`:

```dart
import "other_connection.dart" as other;
import "other_connection.dart";
class Connection extends other.Connection { ... }
class Separation extends Disconnection { ... }
```

Imports with prefixes is one of the tools that Dart provides to avoid name conflicts in imports. The other tool is hiding (using `hide` or `show`), which mainly works to avoid conflicts between different imports.
You can use them as narrowly as you want to (you can add `show Connection` after the `as other` or `hide Connection` after the un-prefixed import, but neither are necessary in this simple case).

Comment: It's a shame that this doesn't seem to be optional, meaning that once applied it has to be specified for all class names in that package/file, even where there is no ambiguity.  For example, I'd like to qualify SearchDelegate in material.dart, but not have to qualify StatelessWidget etc.

Comment: You can import both with and without a prefix in the same file. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I did try this but it ended up not being worth the trouble, especially with a class in the material package.  I ended up just changing my own class's name.